# RestSharp behavior change between versions - Token replacement in rest request parameters

Tags: restsharp

We're upgrading the version of RestSharp that we use in order to gain support for .NET Core.

Old version is 105.2.3, new version is currently 106.4.0 (but the following applies equally to the latest RestSharp code on GITHub)

Given the following code:

```
var request = new RestRequest("/webacs/api/v1/data/{reportType}.json?.full=true&collectionTime=ge({collectionTime})&.firstResult={firstResult}");
request.AddParameter("reportType", "HistoricalClientTraffics", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddParameter("collectionTime", 1497722400000, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddParameter("firstResult", 0, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
```

Using RestSharp 105.2.3, when the request is executed (GET) all three UrlSegment parameters cause token substitution to occur and produce a URL like this:

```
/webacs/api/v1/data/HistoricalClientTraffics.json?.full=true&collectionTime=ge(1497722400000)&.firstResult=0
```

Using RestSharp 106.4.0 (and also the latest RestSharp source from GITHub) only subsitutions of tokens prior to the '?' occur.
Substitutions beyond the '?' no longer occur and a faulty URL is produced:

```
/webacs/api/v1/data/HistoricalClientTraffics.json?.full=true&collectionTime=ge(%7BcollectionTime%7D)&.firstResult=%7BfirstResult%7D
```

(7B and 7D are the ASCII codes for '{' and '}' respectively)

Is this change of behaviour 'by design'?

(It's easy-enough to work around the issue by performing your own token substitutions explicitly)

Comment: This is an issue candidate, I think it's hard to get RestSharp design answers on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed by design. Although technically URL also includes the query, RestSharp is closer to the WebAPI semantics. `UrlSegment` can be seen as the counterpart of `FromRoute` and `QueryParameter` - of `FromQuery`.

So, when you have the URL `http://blah.com/customers/{customerId}` and use the following code:

```
request.AddUrlSerment("customerId", "123");
request.AddQueryParameter("foo", "bar");
```

it will produce a request to `http://blah.com/customers/123?foo=bar`.